# R - describe() output to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, hmisc

I want to create a data frame using describe() function. Dataset under consideration is iris. The data frame should look like this:

```
    Variable    n   missing unique  Info    Mean    0.05    0.1   0.25  0.5    0.75 0.9   0.95
   Sepal.Length 150    0    35      1       5.843   4.6     4.8   5.1   5.8    6.4  6.9   7.255
   Sepal.Width  150    0    23      0.99    3.057   2.345   2.5   2.8   3      3.3  3.61  3.8
Petal.Length    150    0    43      1       3.758   1.3     1.4   1.6   4.35   5.1  5.8   6.1
 Petal.Width    150    0    22      0.99    1.199   0.2     0.2   0.3   1.3    1.8  2.2   2.3
     Species    150    0    3
```

Is there a way out to coerce the output of describe() to data.frame type? When I try to coerce, I get an error as shown below:

```
library(Hmisc)
statistics <- describe(iris)
statistics[1]
first_vec <- statistics[1]$Sepal.Length
as.data.frame(first_vec)
#Error in as.data.frame.default(first_vec) : cannot coerce class ""describe"" to a data.frame
```

Thanks

Comment: You should modify the code for `describe.vector` and alter it so that it produces numeric output of a constant length.

Comment: @akrun - the table in my post is expected output. Thank you for sharing your inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to figure this out is to examine the objects with `str()`:

```
data(iris)
library(Hmisc)
di <- describe(iris)
di
# iris 
# 
# 5  Variables      150  Observations
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Sepal.Length 
#       n missing  unique    Info    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
#     150       0      35       1   5.843   4.600   4.800   5.100   5.800   6.400   6.900   7.255
# 
# lowest : 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7, highest: 7.3 7.4 7.6 7.7 7.9 
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# ...
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Species 
#       n missing  unique 
#     150       0       3 
# 
# setosa (50, 33%), versicolor (50, 33%) 
# virginica (50, 33%) 
# -------------------------------------------------------------
str(di)
# List of 5
# $ Sepal.Length:List of 6
# ..$ descript    : chr "Sepal.Length"
# ..$ units       : NULL
# ..$ format      : NULL
# ..$ counts      : Named chr [1:12] "150" "0" "35" "1" ...
# .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "n" "missing" "unique" "Info" ...
# ..$ intervalFreq:List of 2
# .. ..$ range: atomic [1:2] 4.3 7.9
# .. .. ..- attr(*, "Csingle")= logi TRUE
# .. ..$ count: int [1:100] 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 0 4 0 ...
# ..$ values      : Named chr [1:10] "4.3" "4.4" "4.5" "4.6" ...
# .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" ...
# ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "describe"
# $ Sepal.Width :List of 6
# ...
# $ Species     :List of 5
# ..$ descript: chr "Species"
# ..$ units   : NULL
# ..$ format  : NULL
# ..$ counts  : Named num [1:3] 150 0 3
# .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "n" "missing" "unique"
# ..$ values  : num [1:2, 1:3] 50 33 50 33 50 33
# .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Frequency" "%"
# .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
# ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "describe"
# - attr(*, "descript")= chr "iris"
# - attr(*, "dimensions")= int [1:2] 150 5
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "describe"
```

We see that `di` is a list of lists.  We can take it apart by looking at just the first sublist.  You can convert that into a vector:

```
unlist(di[[1]])
#             descript              counts.n 
#       "Sepal.Length"                 "150" 
#       counts.missing         counts.unique 
#                  "0"                  "35" 
#          counts.Info           counts.Mean 
#                  "1"               "5.843" 
#           counts..05            counts..10 
#              "4.600"               "4.800" 
#           counts..25            counts..50 
#              "5.100"               "5.800" 
#           counts..75            counts..90 
#              "6.400"               "6.900" 
#           counts..95   intervalFreq.range1 
#              "7.255"                 "4.3" 
#  intervalFreq.range2   intervalFreq.count1 
#                "7.9"                   "1" 
#  ...
#            values.H3             values.H2 
#                "7.6"                 "7.7" 
#            values.H1 
#                 "7.9" 
str(unlist(di[[1]]))
# Named chr [1:125] "Sepal.Length" "150" "0" "35" ...
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:125] "descript" "counts.n" "counts.missing" "counts.unique" ...
```

It is very, very long (125).  The elements have been coerced to all be of the same (and most inclusive) type, namely, character.  It seems you want the 2nd through 12th elements:

```
unlist(di[[1]])[2:12]
#     counts.n counts.missing  counts.unique    counts.Info 
#        "150"            "0"           "35"            "1" 
#  counts.Mean     counts..05     counts..10     counts..25 
#      "5.843"        "4.600"        "4.800"        "5.100" 
#   counts..50     counts..75     counts..90 
#      "5.800"        "6.400"        "6.900"
```

Now you have something you can start to work with.  But notice that this only seems to be the case for numerical variables; the factor variable `species` is different:

```
unlist(di[[5]])
#     descript       counts.n counts.missing  counts.unique 
#    "Species"          "150"            "0"            "3" 
#      values1        values2        values3        values4 
#         "50"           "33"           "50"           "33" 
#      values5        values6 
#         "50"           "33"
```

In that case, it seems you only want elements two through four.

Using this process of discovery and problem solving, you can see how you'd take the output of `describe` apart and put the information you want into a data frame.  However, this will take a lot of work.  You'll presumably need to use loops and lots of `if(){ ... } else{ ... }` blocks.  You might just want to code your own dataset description function from scratch.

Comment: One possible starting fpoint for this sort of effort might be: `mtx <- do.call(rbind, sapply(statistics , "[[", "counts")[1:3])`. It is a bit annoying for this effort that the result is character, but that is how Frank handles the varying precision of the columns.

Comment: That's a great start, @42-. It still seems like it's going to take a bit of tedium to get it the rest of the way (eg, the recycling of the vector from the factor variable). I think my preference would still be to decide what I want & code it from scratch.

Comment: @gung - thank you so much for sharing such a descriptive email. This is really helpful. It has solved my purpose.

Comment: @42- thank you for giving a pointer to get the required output with a shorter approach using do.call and sapply functions, instead of following a longer approach. I think, we can treat numeric and factor variables separately as shown below to get required output: num_vars <- do.call(rbind, sapply(statistics , "[[", "counts")[1:4])
fact_var <- do.call(rbind, sapply(statistics , "[[", "counts")[5])

rbind.fill(as.data.frame(num_vars), as.data.frame(fact_var))

Comment: A furter refinement: Consider adding `print(as.data.frame(mtx))`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using the `stat.desc` function from the `pastecs` package:

```
library(pastecs)
summary_df <- stat.desc(mydata)
```

The `summary_df` is the dataframe you wanted. See more info [here](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/descriptives.html).

Answer (score 2):

In R, you just have to use the `summary(iris)` function instead of `describe(iris)` function in Python.